# How can i fetch multiple values with id and store in a variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, mysqli

here is my code of eligible branches i am trying fetch multiple branches with one job id and store the array in a variable `$branches` and i want to send this in a mail body content as `$branches` for example it includes `cse,it,mech` for job id `38`

i am selecting from `r_job_branch` for multiple branches

```
$branchquery=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM r_job_branch where id_job=".$jobId) or die(mysqli_error());
$branchres=$branchquery->fetch_assoc();
$eligiblebranches=$branchres['id_branch'];
```

i am selecting from `r_branch` for multiple branch names

```
$bname=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM r_branch where id_branch=".$eligiblebranches) or die(mysqli_error());
$bres=$bname->fetch_assoc();
$branches=$bres['branch_name'];
```

i want to use that variable in this:

```
$message='<html><body><strong>Eligible Branches:</strong>'.$branches.'</body></html>';
```

Comment: You should try a loop and storing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop around putting out the branch name.

Using a JOINed query and making a guess at how your db connection is working:-

```
<?php

$message = '<html><body><strong>Eligible Branches:</strong>';

$branchquery=$conn->query("SELECT a.id_branch,
                                b.branch_name
                            FROM r_job_branch a
                            INNER JOIN r_branch b
                            ON a.id_branch = b.id_branch
                            where id_job=".$jobId) or die(mysqli_error());

while($bres=$bname->fetch_assoc())
{
    $message .= $bres['branch_name']."<br />";
}
$message .= '</body></html>';
```